# An sufficient and necessary condition for a metric space $X$ to be compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

The problem is this:

Show that a metric space $X$ is compact if and only if the Banach space of bounded continuous functions $C(X)$ with the norm $\|f\| = \sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$ is a separable Banach space.

This is what I think for one direction:

Since $X$ is compact, then $X$ is bounded and separable, thus $d(x,y)$ has an upper bound. I try to use the metric $d$ on $X$ to construct continuous function but still don't know how to do this. Thank you for any help!

Comment: To what end would you like to construct some particular continuous function?

Comment: Just like take countable dense set $A$ in $X$, and for every $a$ in $A$, construct $f_a(x)=d(a,x)$, then I guess polynomials $r_1f_{a_1}(x)+r_2f_{a_2}(x)+...r_kf_{a_k}(x)$ where $r$ are rationals, are dense in $C(X)$.

Comment: So, does it not work? What is your question exactly?

Comment: @EdwardWang What you say may be right - I don't see why. You said polynomial and then wrote a linear combination; it's clear from Stone-Weierstrass that the _polynomials_ (linear combinations of integer powers) of the $f_a$ are in fact dense.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh I actually wanted to say the minimal subalgebra generated by the linear combinations. But how about the other direction then?

Comment: Oh I know how to do the other direction. Let $X$ be not compact, and choose a sequence whose every subsequence all diverge. Then any subset of this sequence is a closed set, then by Urysohn's lemma we can construct uncountable continuous functions each two of them have distance 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ a compact metric space. Let's show that the space $\mathcal{X}=C(X, [-1,1])$ of continuous functions $f \colon X \to [-1,1]$ with the $\max$  distance is separable. Imbed $\mathcal{X}$ into $\mathcal{Y}$, the space of all functions from $X \to [-1,1]$ with the $\sup$ distance.

Here is a very simple and useful lemma. Assume that $\mathcal{X}$ is a subset of a metric space $\mathcal{Y}$ and there exists $B$ countable subset of $\mathcal{Y}$ so that $\bar B \supset \mathcal{X}$. Then there exists a countable subset $A$ of $\mathcal{X}$ so that $\bar A \supset \mathcal{X}$. The idea is to approximately project $B$ onto $\mathcal{X}$. For every $b \in B$, take $a=\phi(b) \in \mathcal{X}$ so that $d(b, a) \le 2 d(b, \mathcal{X})$. Let us show that $\bar \phi(B) \supset \mathcal{X}$. Indeed, take $x \in \mathcal{X}$, and $n >0$. There exists $b\in B$ so that $d(b,x) < \frac{1}{n}$. Now, $d(b, \mathcal{X})< \frac{1}{n}$, so $d(b, \phi(b)) < \frac{2}{n})$. We conclude that $d(x, \phi(b)) < \frac{3}{n}$.

We'll produce now a countable subset $B$ in our $\mathcal{Y}$ so that $\bar B\supset \mathcal{X}$. For that, consider for each $n$ a partitions $\mathcal{P}_n$ of $X$ into sets of size $\le \frac{1}{n}$. Let $B= \cup B_n$, where $B_n$ is the set of functions that are constant on each part of the partition $\mathcal{P}_n$ and take rational values in $[-1,1]$. It is easy to see that for every continuous function $X \to [-1,1]$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a function $g$ in some $B_n$ so that $|f-g|< \epsilon$. Therefore, $\bar B \supset \mathcal{X}$.

Comment: At the end I think you mean $\overline B \supset \mathcal X.$  Surprising how simple this  is compared to a direct attack.....+1 because +2 is not allowed.

Comment: @Daniel Wainfleet: Thank you! It's awfully nondescriptive.  I guess using a separating algebra of functions would be more constructive.

Comment: @Daniel Wainfleet: a more conceptual approach would be to exhibit $X$ as a quotient of a Cantor set and then imbed $C(X)$ into $C(C)$. Of a similar spirit...